# is process running , never works

Tags: c#, .net, process, foreach

I've always had problems with processes, I've never been able to check if a process is running for some reason and i've tried every snippet of code i could find via google but nothing has worked. I've tried different files too. so finally i will ask for help :) here is a snippet among many that has failed to detect even notepad.exe:

```
public bool IsProcessOpen(string name) {
    foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()){
        if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I know how to call the method obviously but like all the others it returns false for any file thats running or not. is it some kind of bug?

Comment: Have you tried enumerating the list of processes to see what's returned and what their names are?

Comment: your code is OK, what `name` are you testing? does the account you run the code under have enough permissions to list the processes?

Answer (score 3):

You won't find `notepad.exe`, since its `ProcessName` is just `notepad`.

[image]

You could trim the extension using:

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name)
```

Also you can reduce your method body to one line:

```
return Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name)).Length > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You method is fine. Perhaps you are having problems with upper and lower case? You can improve your check by mapping to upper case in the if statement:

```
clsProcess.ProcessName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(name.ToUpperInvariant())
```

Then `notepad`, `Notepad` and `NOTEPAD` will all match the process named `notepad`.

Comment: aha it seems most of you "or all" were correct.. i was looking for notepad.exe/file.exe when infact i should have removed the ext *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

This has always worked for me

```
if(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Length == 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will not work for stopped working process.

Answer (score 0):

This checks to see if a process is running and changes the color of a button. 
Be sure you have the name correct: some take dot exe and some do not. This is checking the system process'.

```
   Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
        if (proc.Length == 0)
        {
            btnlogon.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
        }
        else
        {
            btnlogon.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
```